# React SyntheticEvent onCopy does not work for select element

Tags: reactjs

The onCopy event works fine for every HTML element. 
**Why it does not work with HTML select Tag?**

https://codesandbox.io/s/new-fog-ktbuh

Answer (score 2):

Select menus do not permit selection of the text of an option, only identifying an option as the current value. If you can't select something, you can't copy it. ‍♂️

Comment: So Is there any we we can approach this problem?

Comment: That depends on what you're trying to do. The question you posed was requesting information, not a solution. :-) If you simply want the value a user chose, the standard solution is to listen for a change event insteadof a copy event, then retrieve `event.currentTarget.value`.